# Route that handles registration request return 404

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to let someone register but when I click the register button I get 404 not found.
I've had this issue before but that was cuz of how the routes were ordered but as you can see I only have 2 in this project and the csrf is also implemented as required...

My form:

```
<!-- register form -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('register') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Your username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                @if ($errors->has('username'))
                    <br><span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <br><span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Your password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <br><span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="repeat-password">Repeat your password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="repeat-password">
                @if ($errors->has('repeat-password'))
                    <br><span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('repeat-password') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
```

My web.php file with my routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/register', 'PagesController@register')->name('register');
```

This is my controller handling the functions:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\RegistrationRequest;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('pages.home');
    }

    public function register(RegistrationRequest $request) {
        $user = new User;
        $user->username = $request->input('username');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = $request->bcrypt(input('password'));
        $user->save();

        session()->flash('status', 'Your account has been created!');
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

Lastly the registration request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RegistrationRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:30',
            'email' => 'email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: please ensure there are no active middlewares intercepting `/register` route.

Comment: @AshishPatel I don't have an active middleware and the authorize function in the request is true so shouldn't this just work?

Comment: You only have a POST route set for `/register` - but you need a GET.  Also, why roll your own registration?  [Laravel has all this built in](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication).  Security is hard - don't roll your own.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've starded a new project using all the scaffolding and preset views from laravel 7.x and the only thing that works is the '/' route. Haven't changed anything in the project...

I used laravel new project --auth as recommended in the documentation.

Comment: The link in my comment describes how to install the built-in auth.  You do not need to add your own routes, controllers, views, forms ... it is all auto-magically added by Laravel.  You would only need to edit or add to that if the built in functionality doesn't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

So apperantly after installing the ui package all my custom routes stopped working. So starting a new project with the same code except the package works.